# Validating a optional, virtual attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a pedigree app that will take in an animal's name and inserts it in to an Animal model. Adding the animal's parents needs to be encouraged, but not required. For example, as you go back through the pedigree, we lose information about who begot whom. I have the parents' name as a virtual attribute that searches the other animals by their name rather than by `animal_id` in the model, since no one would refer to the other animals by the `animal_id`, rather it would be by their name. But, if someone enters a bogus animal name, then I need to make that update invalid.

My virtual attribute is like this...

```
def mother_name=(name)
    record = animals.find_by(name: name)
    if(record)
        self.mother = record
    else
        self.errors.add(:mother, "does not exist in database. Add her before this animal")
    end
end

def mother_name
    mother_name
end
```

When I use the console and change the mother's name to something bogus, then the errors attribute is populated correctly. When I do `valid?` on the object, it comes back as true and the `errors.messages` have been flushed. I need a way for it to come back as false and to leave the `errors.messages` intact.

I have also added a `validates` function to see whether the mother's name is in the model, but by the time `validates` is run, I get an error saying that nil doesn't have an attribute called `mother_name`. Also, doing two `find_by`'s seems a bit of a hack.

Again, I want the mother's and father's names to be optional since we may not have records of who the parent is for previous generations - but if it is given, it needs to be correct.

Comment: I would use ajax to perform a search for the parent in the form rather than add a bunch of complication to the backend. Less hacky and better UX.

Comment: Instead of looking at the problem from a coding POV look at the user story. How will this feature actually work for the user? In this vase it might give very confusing results as you will need to deal with multiple pets with the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this with a proper rails validation, i.e.,

```
class Animal < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :mother_name

  validate :mother_name_valid

  private

  def mother_name_valid
    mother = Animal.find_by(name: mother_name)

    if mother_name.present? && mother.nil?
      self.errors.add(:mother_name, "does not exist in database. Add her before this animal")
    elsif mother.present?
      self.mother = mother
    end         
  end
end
```

Hope this helps you. Alternatively you could write

```
class Animal < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :mother_name

  validate :mother_name_valid, if: proc { |animal| animal.mother_name.present? }

  private

  def mother_name_valid
    mother = Animal.find_by(name: mother_name)

    if mother.nil?
      self.errors.add(:mother_name, "does not exist in database. Add her before this animal")
    else
      self.mother = mother
    end
  end
end
```

with an `if proc`.

Comment: Thanks for the help - turns out your answer was close - in the first one option you suggested, i put `if mother_name.present?` above the `mother=...` line to make having the mother name optional.